# Why does LinkGenerator.GetUriByPage() "values" parameter return string.Length when a string is passed in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core, just learning some new concepts...

When I generate a link using

```
public static string GetUriByPage (this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.LinkGenerator generator, 
                                    string page, string handler, object values, 
                                    string scheme, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HostString host, 
                                    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString pathBase = default, 
                                    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FragmentString fragment = default, 
                                    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.LinkOptions options = default);
```

the `values` field takes an input as type `object`. If I try to insert a string as the object, it will take the value of the `Length` string property instead of the value of the string variable. I'm assuming the `values` field gets all the public properties of object, and that's how it works, but how would I be able to pass in just the string value and not the public properties?

I'm trying to I just want to understand why this is the case, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.pagelinkgeneratorextensions.geturibypage?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Routing_PageLinkGeneratorExtensions_GetUriByPage_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Routing_LinkGenerator_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_String_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HostString_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_PathString_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_FragmentString_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Routing_LinkOptions_) doesn't have much info on the behaviour behind-the-scenes.

**Test Code**

```
// Create a new entry in the hash table
var record = _context.HashRecords.Add(new Data.HashRecord {
    FullName = user.FullName,
    Representative = repName,
    Hash = GetUniqueKey(8)
});

_context.SaveChangesAsync();

string generatedLink = _linkGenerator.GetUriByPage("/Page",
                       handler: null,
                       values: record.Entity,
                       scheme: _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme,
                       host: _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host);
```

Comment: It’s documented here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/PageLinkGeneratorExtensions.cs 

Comment: Yes, that is the documentation, but that doesn't explain why the "values" parameter returns String.Length when a string is passed in instead of the value of the string. I suspect it's not specifically an Asp.Net Core issue, but rather something I'm not understanding about C#...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `values` parameter is passed to `RouteValueDictionary` class constructor. That class expects a key/value set or an object which properties, and their values, are used to create the dictionary. That is why you see `String.Length`.

You can pass an anonymous object with the value you want to resolve the URL. (Change the property name to your convenience)

```
// Create a new entry in the hash table
var record = _context.HashRecords.Add(new Data.HashRecord {
    FullName = user.FullName,
    Representative = repName,
    Hash = GetUniqueKey(8)
});

_context.SaveChangesAsync();

string generatedLink = _linkGenerator.GetUriByPage("/Page",
                       handler: null,
                       // Passing an object to be converted to dictionary
                       values: new { entity = record.Entity },
                       scheme: _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme,
                       host: _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host);
```

You can see the passing of `values` parameters to `RouteValueDictonary` in the documentation in line `232` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/PageLinkGeneratorExtensions.cs).